# Find $(this) when using jQuery on with dynamically created elements

Tags: ajax, jquery

Lets say I have a list where the `li` are created dynamically, via AJAX :

```
​<ul id="demo-list"> 
    <li data-test="test1" >Test 1</li>
    <li data-test="test2" >Test 2</li>
    <li data-test="test3" >Test 3</li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

When one of the `li` is clicked, I want to get the data attribute test of that particular `li`.

I tried something like :

```
$('#demo-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    console.log($(this).find('li').data('test'));
});
```

But it obviously gets all the list items and not just the particular one where the event happens.

Also, I know how to do this with `.live()`, but my question is how to do it via `.on()`

Comment: Personally i believe this needs to be done with .live() since the objects are not available statically.

Comment: @ericosg Never use `live()` since 1.7 it has been deprecated in favour of `on()` - and even before that `live()` was slow. You should use `delegate()` instead in earlier versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove the find from after your `$(this)` call:

```
$('#demo-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
console.log($(this).data('test'));
})
```

You can find the working example bellow:

> http://jsfiddle.net/P356B/2/

EDIT:

if you have a widget/plugin that generates that content perhaps you could just attach the click event handler in the plugin. or have a construct such as:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
   $('#demo-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
   console.log($(this).data('test'));
   })
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: No, I tried that first. In this context $(this) refers to $('#demo-list')

Comment: It works there, but it wont work if the list items are dynamically generated.

Comment: then perhaps this is not the problem, please update your question with the rest of the script that generates the lists

Comment: There is relay nothing special. Just a simple ajax call.

Comment: My bad. I was making a mistake when calling the function. I had the li selector wrapped like a jquery object, and that was the cause of the problem :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j8enw/ same fiddle as Bogdan, except it includes a link to add more items to the ul.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want `find`. Just do

```
console.log($(this).data('test'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this :

```
 console.log($(this).data('test'));
```

check here : http://jsfiddle.net/wDzkW/4/